# POS .net not releasing MSR

Tags: c#, opos, pos-for-.net

I use an MSR device in my application which is working as expected while the application runs. However if my application crashes or is forcibly closed the MSR is not released and cannot be reclaimed (although it can still be opened and closed). Through experimentation I have discovered that if I log the user off or re-start the OPOS Control Service all is then OK.

I don't believe that hard coding a service re-start is the way to go and would rather force the device to be released on error.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your measures will be realistic.

When an application crashes or hangs up, ownership of the used resource or open state is often left as it is.

Frequently done are system shutdown and restart.
User logoff and re-logon are countermeasures accordingly.

If you can safely terminate the application, you can also restart only the application, keeping the system running in the logon state.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. My application exits cleanly when intentionally ended by the user. I am trying to ensure that if the system crashes during use it will release all claimed devices so that it may be restarted without a user log-off/log-on or system restart. I have other OPOS devices (Line Display etc.) which are successfully released but not so the MSR. My question was is there a way to force the release of this device?

Comment: It depends on the mechanism inside the service object you are using. It is concerned whether or not it is programmed assuming that the object is destroyed even though the Close method is not explicitly called.
Or the service object uses resources outside the process for Claim/Release control. Due to some difference, MSR service object you using may be weak mechanism for crashing and hanging up. Please consider requesting improvement from MSR vendor or trying MSR of another vendor.

Comment: Hi Kunif. Many thanks for your reply. This is a really strange one, when I force the application to crash I can open() and close() the device but If I try to Claim() it an exception is thrown. I have tried 2 different MSR's each running on different POS hardware but the result is the same. In order to recover I have to either shutdown.re-start, log-off/log-on or restart the service.

Comment: There is a possibility that this may be caused by exclusive control processing at the time of Claim. At this time, service object executes processing using named mutex / global atom / lock file / something else, when restarting the application after the crash, it is considered that an abnormal state is detected at the time of Claim and its recovery is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

catch the exception and call a fiscalprinter.ResetPrinter() method quit